# (In)Stability of equilibrium points depicted in a vector plot?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

(i)

Consider the system:

$$\frac{dS}{dt} =-\frac{\beta S I }{N}+ \gamma I$$
$$\frac{dI}{dt} = \frac{\beta S I }{N} - \gamma I$$

where $N=S+I$.

The equilibrium points being:

$$e_1:(S^*, I^*) = (N,0)$$
$$e_2:(S^*, I^*) = \left(\frac{\gamma N}{\beta}, \frac{N(\beta-\gamma)}{\beta} \right)$$

For simplicity we normalise $N$ to $1$.

The eigenvalues for $e_1$ (after substituting $e_1$ into the Jacobian) being:

$$ \lambda_1 =0,\\ \lambda_2 = \beta - \gamma.$$

The eigenvalues for $e_2$ (after substituting $e_2$ into the Jacobian) being:

$$\lambda_1 =0,\\ \lambda_2 = \gamma - \beta.$$

From the Jacobian we know $e_1$ is stable if $\beta < \gamma$ (or $R_0<1$) and unstable if $\beta>\gamma$ (or $R_0>1$).

Similarly for $e_2$ we see it is stable for $\beta > \gamma$ (or $R_0 > 1$) and unstable if $\beta<\gamma$ (or $R_0<1$).

How can we show these 4 plots where $R_0<1$ in one case and $R_0>1$ in another?

(ii)

$$\frac{dS}{dt}=-\frac{\beta S I}{N} + \xi R$$

$$\frac{dI}{dt}=\frac{\beta S I}{N} - \gamma I$$

$$\frac{dR}{dt}=\gamma I - \xi R$$

where $N=S+I+R$.

The equilibrium points being:

$$e_1 : (S^*,I^*, R^*) = \left(N, 0, 0 \right)$$
$$e_2 : (S^*, I^*, R^*) = \left(\frac{N\gamma}{\beta}, \frac{N\xi}{\gamma + \xi}\left(1- \frac{\gamma}{\beta}\right), \frac{N \gamma}{\gamma + \xi}\left(1-\frac{\gamma}{\beta} \right)    \right)$$

The eigenvalues for $e_1$ (after substituting $e_1$ into the Jacobian) being:

$$\lambda_1 =0,\\ \lambda_2 = -\xi, \\ \lambda_3 = \beta- \gamma.$$

The eigenvalues for $e_2$ (after substituting $e_2$ into the Jacobian) being:

$$\lambda_1 =0,\\ \lambda_2 = \frac{-\xi\left(\beta +\xi\right) + \sqrt{\xi^2 \left(\beta +\xi\right)^2 -4\xi \left(\gamma+\xi\right)^2\left(\beta -\gamma\right)} }{2\left(\gamma + \xi\right)}, \\[2ex] \lambda_3 = \frac{-\xi\left(\beta +\xi\right) - \sqrt{\xi^2 \left(\beta +\xi\right)^2 -4\xi \left(\gamma+\xi\right)^2\left(\beta -\gamma\right)} }{2\left(\gamma + \xi\right)}.$$

Stability of $e_2$ has different cases, for different inputs $(\beta,\gamma$ and $\xi)$ we have three different stability points; a saddle point, a stable node, and a stable focus. How can we show this in a vector plot?

**EDIT**

Addendum (i)

Consider the system:

$$\frac{dS}{dt}=-\frac{\beta S I}{N}$$
$$\frac{dI}{dt}=\frac{\beta S I}{N}$$

where $N=S+I$.

The equilibrium points I have are:

$$e_1 : \left( S_1^*, I_1^*\right)= \left(N, 0\right), \\
e_2 : \left( S_1^*, I_1^*\right)= \left(0, N\right)$$

But this model is a little strange because I get an answer of (s,i) = (0,0) when I use your code.. any ideas why?

Addendum (ii)

$$\frac{dS}{dt}=\mu N -\frac{\beta S I}{N} -\nu S$$

$$\frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{\beta S I}{N} - \sigma E - \nu E$$

$$\frac{dI}{dt}=\sigma E -\nu I$$

where $N=S+E+I$ is the total population.

Using your code:

```
e := n - s - i;
SetModel[{Pop[
    pop] -> {Component[
      s] -> {Equation :> \[Mu] n - \[Beta] s i/n - \[Nu] s}, 
    Component[i] -> {Equation :> \[Sigma] e - \[Nu] i}}, 
  Parameters :> {\[Beta] > 0, \[Sigma] > 0, \[Mu] > 0, \[Nu] > 0, 
    n > 0}}]
eq = SolveEcoEq[]
```

gives:

```
{{s -> (n \[Nu]^2 + n \[Beta] \[Sigma] + n \[Nu] \[Sigma] - 
    Sqrt[-4 \[Beta] \[Sigma] (n^2 \[Mu] \[Nu] + 
        n^2 \[Mu] \[Sigma]) + (-n \[Nu]^2 - n \[Beta] \[Sigma] - 
       n \[Nu] \[Sigma])^2])/(2 \[Beta] \[Sigma]), 
  i -> (-((n \[Nu]^2)/\[Beta]) + n \[Sigma] - (
    n \[Nu] \[Sigma])/\[Beta] + 
    Sqrt[-4 \[Beta] \[Sigma] (n^2 \[Mu] \[Nu] + 
        n^2 \[Mu] \[Sigma]) + (-n \[Nu]^2 - n \[Beta] \[Sigma] - 
       n \[Nu] \[Sigma])^2]/\[Beta])/(2 (\[Nu] + \[Sigma]))}, {s -> (
   n \[Nu]^2 + n \[Beta] \[Sigma] + n \[Nu] \[Sigma] + 
    Sqrt[-4 \[Beta] \[Sigma] (n^2 \[Mu] \[Nu] + 
        n^2 \[Mu] \[Sigma]) + (-n \[Nu]^2 - n \[Beta] \[Sigma] - 
       n \[Nu] \[Sigma])^2])/(2 \[Beta] \[Sigma]), 
  i -> (-((n \[Nu]^2)/\[Beta]) + n \[Sigma] - (
    n \[Nu] \[Sigma])/\[Beta] - 
    Sqrt[-4 \[Beta] \[Sigma] (n^2 \[Mu] \[Nu] + 
        n^2 \[Mu] \[Sigma]) + (-n \[Nu]^2 - n \[Beta] \[Sigma] - 
       n \[Nu] \[Sigma])^2]/\[Beta])/(2 (\[Nu] + \[Sigma]))}}
```

which seems incorrect as we don't have a disease-free equilibrium point. My equilibrium points were:

$$e_1 : \left( S_1^*, E_1^*, I_1^*\right)= \left(N, 0, 0\right), \\
e_2 : \left( S_2^*, E_2^*, I_2^*\right)= \left(\frac{N\nu\left(\sigma + \nu\right)}{\beta \sigma},\frac{N\nu^2 \left( \sigma + \nu \right) \left( \frac{\beta \sigma}{\nu\left(\sigma+\nu\right)} -1 \right) }{\beta\sigma\left(\sigma +\nu \right)} , \frac{N\nu\sigma \left( \sigma + \nu \right) \left( \frac{\beta \sigma}{\nu\left(\sigma+\nu\right)} -1 \right) }{\beta\sigma\left(\sigma +\nu \right)}\right)\\\\$$

The plot using the following:

```
\[Beta] = 0.6; \[Sigma] = 0.2; \[Mu] = 0.3; \[Nu] = 0.3; n = 1;
eq = SolveEcoEq[]
N[EcoEigenvalues[eq[[2]]]]
Show[PlotEcoPhasePlane[{s, 0, 1.6}, {i, -0.5, 1}], 
 RuleListPlot[eq, PlotMarkers -> EcoStableQ[eq]]]
```

[image]

And similarly

```
\[Beta] = 0.6; \[Sigma] = 0.4; \[Mu] = 0.2; \[Nu] = 0.2; n = 1;
eq = SolveEcoEq[]
N[EcoEigenvalues[eq[[2]]]]
Show[PlotEcoPhasePlane[{s, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 1}], 
 RuleListPlot[eq, PlotMarkers -> EcoStableQ[eq]]]
```

[image]

Addendum (iii)

$$\frac{dS}{dt}=\mu N -\frac{\beta S I}{N} + \gamma I -\nu S$$

$$\frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{\beta S I}{N} - \sigma E - \nu E$$

$$\frac{dI}{dt}=\sigma E - \gamma I -\nu I$$

where $N=S+E+I$ is the total population.

Using your code, we have:

```
e := n - s - i;
SetModel[{Pop[
    pop] -> {Component[
      s] -> {Equation :> \[Mu] n - \[Beta] s i/
          n + \[Gamma] i - \[Nu] s}, 
    Component[i] -> {Equation :> \[Sigma] e - \[Gamma] i - \[Nu] i}}, 
  Parameters :> {\[Beta] > 0, \[Gamma] > 0, \[Sigma] > 0, \[Mu] > 
     0, \[Nu] > 0, n > 0}}]
eq = SolveEcoEq[]
```

giving:

```
{{s -> n, i -> 0}, {s -> (n \[Gamma])/\[Beta], 
  i -> -((n (-\[Beta] + \[Gamma]) \[Sigma])/(\[Beta] (\[Gamma] + \
\[Sigma])))}}
```

The first equilibrium point is correct however the second is wrong, from my results anyway. I get:

$$e_2 : \left( S_2^*, E_2^*, I_2^*\right)= \left(\frac{N \left(\gamma+\nu\right)\left(\sigma+\nu \right)}{\beta \sigma}, \frac{N\left(\gamma+\nu\right)^2\left(\sigma+\nu\right)}{\beta\sigma \left(\gamma + \sigma+\nu\right)}\left(\frac{\beta\sigma}{\left(\gamma+\nu\right)\left(\sigma+\nu\right)}-1\right), \frac{N\sigma\left(\gamma+\nu\right)\left(\sigma+\nu\right)}{\beta\sigma \left(\gamma + \sigma+\nu\right)}\left(\frac{\beta\sigma}{\left(\gamma+\nu\right)\left(\sigma+\nu\right)}-1\right)\right)\\[1ex]$$

Can you do what you did in your answer below for the addendum systems?

Comment: Take a look at the examples in the documentation of `StreamPlot`, particularly the [Applications section](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot.html#305286942)

Comment: Please do not post LateX code; there's no easy way to copy this into Mathematica to try things out. Make it easy for people to try and answer your question.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit whenever I try posting a question using math mode, I get formatting errors for some reason..

Comment: @Math Re: formatting, you don't need the spaces before display equations.  As for your addendum problem ii), is there an $R$ missing or a typo?  Right now $N=S+E+I$ is not constant -- if you check $dN/dt=dS/dt+dE/dt+dI/dt$ it doesn't equal zero.

Comment: @ChrisK there is no $R$ missing. This is the SEIS model. I should've mentioned $\mu = \nu$ to maintain constant population hence the summation of the system will be zero. I have given the bounty and best answer to you but I hope you can help me out with the addendum :)

Comment: @Math Thanks! Have you given these extra problems a try? They should be simple modifications of the other cases (especially addendum (i), which is just the original problem (i) with $\gamma=0$).

Comment: @ChrisK I will try them tomorrow then get back to you hopefully tomorrow :)

Comment: @ChrisK I did try them, but I think I'm getting incorrect results.

Comment: @ChrisK Regarding the formatting, I only put them in so I can edit and post the question. When I type it out in the "normal" way, it says formatting errors. Anyway, I hope you can fix these last few systems! after adjusting for the new system for some reason for the above systems, I'm getting the wrong equilibrium points which is messing the whole plot up...

Comment: @Math Let's see what you got

Comment: @ChrisK I will add it in the question

Comment: @ChrisK I just checked, the vector plots work(somewhat ?), however the "true" isoclines are not showing like the other models thus giving weird vectors plots. The eigenvalues are identical(I checked manually with my results by substituting a few points). You'll know what I'm talking about when you try plot the addendums.

Comment: @ChrisK I hope you can answer my question(s). I am waiting upon your answer, it will be beneficial to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make it easy, I'll use my [EcoEvo package](https://github.com/cklausme/EcoEvo).

First time, you'll need to install it:

```
PacletInstall["EcoEvo", "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/cklausme/EcoEvo/master"]
```

Then, load the package to get started:

```
<<EcoEvo`
```

Both models are a little bit funny, in that total population size is conserved.  Thus, model (i) is effectively one-dimensional and model (ii) is effectively two-dimensional.

### Model (i): SI

```
SetModel[{
  Pop[pop] -> {
    Component[s] -> {Equation :> -β s i/n + γ i},
    Component[i] -> {Equation :> β s i/n - γ i}
  },
  Parameters :> {β > 0, γ > 0, n > 0}
}]
```

Let's go straight to the phase planes using [PlotEcoPhasePlane](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/docs/ref/PlotEcoPhasePlane.nb), manually adding the total population constraint as a pink straight line.  The no-disease case (disease-free equilibrium `eq[[1]]` is stable, the other equilibrium `eq[[2]]` is biologically meaningless since `s > n` and `i < 0`):

```
β = 0.95; γ = 1; n = 1;
Show[
 PlotEcoPhasePlane[{s, 0.9, 1.1}, {i, -0.1, 0.1}],
 Plot[n - s, {s, 0.9, 1.1}, PlotStyle -> Pink],
 RuleListPlot[{{s -> n, i -> 0}, {s -> (n γ)/β, i -> n - (n γ)/β}}, PlotMarkers -> {True, False}]
 ]
```

[image]

and the endemic case (endemic equilibrium `eq[[2]]` is stable):

```
β = 4; γ = 1; n = 1;
Show[
 PlotEcoPhasePlane[{s, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 1}],
 Plot[n - s, {s, 0, n}, PlotStyle -> Pink],
 RuleListPlot[{{s -> n, i -> 0}, {s -> (n γ)/β, i -> n - (n γ)/β}}, PlotMarkers -> {False, True}]
]
```

[image]

Again, because of the total-population constraint, this is effectively a one-dimensional system with either two or one feasible (non-negative) equilibria.  Note that the two different isoclines ($S$ and $I$) overlap completely because of this and just look gold.

### Model (ii): SIR

Here we can get rid of the degeneracy by defining `r := n - s - i`, then work in the SI phase-plane.

```
r := n - s - i;
SetModel[{
  Pop[pop] -> {
    Component[s] -> {Equation :> -β s i/n + ξ r},
    Component[i] -> {Equation :> β s i/n - γ i}
  },
  Parameters :> {β > 0, γ > 0, ξ > 0, n > 0}
}]
```

To verify your analytical results:

```
eq = SolveEcoEq[]
```

[image]

```
EcoEigenvalues[eq[[1]]]
```

[image]

```
EcoEigenvalues[eq[[2]]]
```

[image]

The eigenvalues of the non-trivial equilibrium are ugly, but we can check stability using Routh-Hurwitz criteria in [EcoStableQ](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/docs/ref/EcoStableQ.nb):

```
Simplify[EcoStableQ[eq[[2]]]]
```

[image]

On to the phase planes.  The $S$-isocline is blue, the $I$-isocline is gold.

No-disease case (`eq[[1]]` is stable, `eq[[2]]` is a biologically meaningless saddle point):

```
β = 0.95; γ = 1; ξ = 1; n = 1;
eq = SolveEcoEq[]
N[EcoEigenvalues[eq[[2]]]]
Show[
 PlotEcoPhasePlane[{s, 0.9, 1.1}, {i, -0.1, 0.1}],
 RuleListPlot[eq, PlotMarkers -> EcoStableQ[eq]]
]
(* {{s -> 1., i -> 0}, {s -> 1.05263, i -> -0.0263158}} *)
(* {-1.02384, 0.0488359} *)
```

[image]

Endemic case 1 (`eq[[2]]` is a stable focus, due to complex eigenvalues):

```
β = 4; γ = 1; ξ = 1; n = 1;
eq = SolveEcoEq[]
N[EcoEigenvalues[eq[[2]]]]
Show[
 PlotEcoPhasePlane[{s, 0, 1.1}, {i, 0, 1.1}],
 RuleListPlot[eq, PlotMarkers -> EcoStableQ[eq]]
]
(* {{s -> 1, i -> 0}, {s -> 1/4, i -> 3/8}} *)
(* {-1.25 + 1.19896 I, -1.25 - 1.19896 I} *)
```

[image]

Endemic case 2 (`eq[[2]]` is a stable node, due to negative real eigenvalues):

```
β = 4; γ = 1; ξ = 10; n = 1;
eq = SolveEcoEq[]
N[EcoEigenvalues[eq[[2]]]]
Show[
 PlotEcoPhasePlane[{s, 0, 1.1}, {i, 0, 1.1}],
 RuleListPlot[eq, PlotMarkers -> EcoStableQ[eq]]
]
(* {{s -> 1, i -> 0}, {s -> 1/4, i -> 15/22}} *)
(* {-9.60337, -3.1239} *)
```

[image]

Comment: This is nice, however can we show all four vector plots for say part (i)? stable and unstable plots for both $e_1$ and $e_2$ for a given $R_0$?  Currently we only see the respective Vector plots as a result of our inputs.

Comment: Also, in model (ii), we have a saddle point when $\beta = 0.95$, $\gamma=1$ and $\xi=0.5$

Comment: Also, the total population line(blue line) isn't a linear in model (ii) (stable focus plot), why?

Comment: @Math I tried to clarify my answer.  I made the total-population constraint line pink in model (i), to distinguish it from the isoclines.  The total-population constraint doesn't show up in model (ii), because we use it to eliminate $R$ to make the system two-dimensional.  I extended the axes in the no-disease case to show the other equilibrium, but it's biologically meaningless ($S>N$ and $I<0$ don't make biological sense).  Finally, since you can now see both equilibria in every plot, there's no need for separate figures for each equilibrium (in fact, it's nice to see the global picture).

Comment: I should add, you have the zero eigenvalues because you work on the full system and I don't have them in model (ii) because I have eliminated $R$.

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense, but could you work on the full system? I'm sure it wont be difficult to adjust. This is because I consider other models too so I can apply the same technique provided here to the other models. I will also attach a model including vital dynamics as an addendum so that you can check whether what I did is correct.

Comment: Actually, never mind, I will switch all my models to the SI plane. Also in model (i) how do you find the exact points of intersection in both plots? I will add the addendum on Monday.

Comment: @Math Reducing the dimension of the system is usually a great idea when possible.  If you want to use the phase plane, that basically requires a two-dimensional system (since it's a plane).  I found the intersections in model i) using `SolveEcoEq[]` but it is a little weird due to the degeneracy, so I put those in manually.

Comment: I meant, how do we find the numerical values at the intersection points? I will add the addendum today, but the formatting will crash again so hopefully you can sort it out again.