# (In)Stability of equilibrium points in a vector plot (continued)?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, stability

I got a nice answer from Chris to my earlier question(though there are still some points unanswered): [(In)Stability of equilibrium points depicted in a vector plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250081/instability-of-equilibrium-points-depicted-in-a-vector-plot)

Now consider the following system:

```
$$    
            \begin{align}
            \frac{dS}{dt} &= \nu N -\frac{\beta S I}{N} + \xi R - \nu S\\
            \frac{dE}{dt} &= \frac{\beta S I}{N}- \sigma E -\nu E  \\[2ex]
            \frac{dI}{dt} &= \sigma E -\gamma I -\nu I \\[2ex]
            \frac{dR}{dt} &= \gamma I -\xi R - \nu R
            \end{align}
$$
```

where $N = S + E + I + R$ is the total population.

If we apply the same technique we have:

```
r := 1 - s - e - i;
SetModel[{
  Pop[pop] -> {
    Component[s] -> {Equation :> ξ + ν - ξ e - ξ i - β s i  - ξ s - ν s}, 
    Component[e] -> {Equation :>  β s i - σ e - ν e }, 
    Component[i] -> {Equation :> σ e - γ i - ν i }
  },
  Parameters :> {β > 0, γ > 0, ξ > 0, σ > 0, ν > 0}
}]
eq = SolveEcoEq[]
```

We get:
[image]

Which is fine. Now I want to do the following;

```
β = 0.7; γ = 0.3; σ = 0.3; ξ = 0.4; ν = 0.3;
eq = SolveEcoEq[]
N[EcoEigenvalues[eq[[2]]]]
Show[PlotEcoPhasePlane[{s, 0, 2}, {e, -0.6, 1}], 
 RuleListPlot[eq, PlotMarkers -> EcoStableQ[eq]]]
```

Our system is 3 dimensional so how would I plot phase planes for say $s$ vs $i$ or $s$ vs $e$ etc? What about initial conditions for the phase portraits?

EDIT:

The paper:

https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7390/5/1/7/htm

Hopefully you can recreate the results!

My code for ODE solution:

```
tmax = 100;
\[Beta] = 4;
\[Sigma] = 1/3;
\[Gamma] = 1/7;
b = (1.9/100)/365;
d = (0.8/100)/365;
\[Alpha] = 1/14;
\[Nu] = 0.8;
\[Rho] = 0.5;
SExPRS = NDSolveValue[{
    S'[t] == \[Alpha] + 
      b (1 - \[Nu]) - \[Alpha]*Ex[t] - \[Alpha]*P[t] - \[Beta]*S[t]*
       P[t] - (b + \[Rho] + \[Alpha])*S[t],
    Ex'[t] == \[Beta]*S[t]*P[t] - (b + \[Sigma])*Ex[t],
    P'[t] == \[Sigma]*Ex[t] - (b + \[Gamma])*P[t],
    S[0] == 0.25,
    Ex[0] == 0.25,
    P[0] == 0.25},
   {S, Ex, P},
   {t, 0, tmax}];
{f1, f2, f3} = SExPRS;

st = Style[#, 15, Black] &;

Plot[{f1[t], f2[t], f3[t], 1 - f1[t] - f2[t] - f3[t], 1, 0}, {t, 0, 
  tmax}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange, Red, Green, 
   Directive[Black, Dashed], Directive[Black, Dashed]}, Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> st /@ {"Time", "Density"}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Orange, Red, Green, Black}, {"S(t)", 
     "E(t)", "I(t)", "R(t)" }, LegendFunction -> Framed], {0.85, 
    0.44}], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Compared to your eco package:

```
r := 1 - s - e - i;
SetModel[{Pop[
    pop] -> {Component[
      s] -> {Equation :> \[Xi] + \[Nu] (1 - 
           c) - \[Xi] e - \[Xi] i - \[Beta] s i  - \[Xi] s - \[Nu] s \
- \[Rho] s}, 
    Component[
      e] -> {Equation :>  \[Beta] s i - \[Sigma] e - \[Nu] e }, 
    Component[
      i] -> {Equation :> \[Sigma] e - \[Gamma] i - \[Nu] i }}, 
  Parameters :> {\[Beta] > 0, \[Gamma] > 0, \[Xi] > 0, \[Sigma] > 
     0, \[Nu] > 0, \[Rho] > 0, c > 0}}]
eq = SolveEcoEq[]
    \[Beta] = 4; \[Gamma] = 1/7; \[Sigma] = 1/3; \[Xi] = 
     1/14; c = 0.8; \[Nu] = (1.9/100)/365; \[Rho] = 0.5;
    eq = SolveEcoEq[]
    N[EcoEigenvalues[eq[[2]]]]
    Show[PlotEcoPhasePlane[{s, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 1}, 
      Fixed -> {e -> \[Sigma]}], 
     RuleListPlot[eq, PlotMarkers -> EcoStableQ[eq]]]
    sol = EcoSim[{s -> 0.25, e -> 0.25, i -> 0.25}, 90];
    PlotDynamics[sol]
```

[image]

An example of $e$ plotted against $i$:

[image]

Comment: @Moo Nope, to be honest, I'm an amateur in Mathematica

Comment: @Moo can you help?

Comment: BTW, be sure to use `:>`, not `->` after `Equation` in `SetModel`.

Answer (score 4):

Nice to see you trying my [EcoEvo package](https://github.com/cklausme/EcoEvo).  I will increase $\beta$ to get the disease to persist at a stable positive equilibrium.

```
β = 2;

eq = SolveEcoEq[]
EcoStableQ[eq]
(* {{s -> 1., e -> 0, i -> 0}, {s -> 0.6, e -> 0.233333, i -> 0.116667}} *)
(* {False, True} *)

sol = EcoSim[{s -> 0.999, e -> 0.001, i -> 0}, 100];
PlotDynamics[sol]
```

[image]
[PlotEcoPhasePlane](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/docs/ref/PlotEcoPhasePlane.nb) takes the option `Fixed`, which you can use to fix other variables to get a 2D slice.  For example,

```
PlotEcoPhasePlane[{s, 0, 1}, {e, 0, 1}, Fixed -> {i -> 0}]
```

[image]

However, I'm not sure how useful this is, because the fixed variable `i` actually changes, which you can't see in such a 2D slice of the 3D phase space.  One idea would be to assume a quasi-steady state between exposed `e` and infected `i` by setting $di/dt=0$, solving for $i$ in terms of $e$, then using that in your 2D phase plane:

```
PlotEcoPhasePlane[{s, 0, 1}, {e, 0, 1}, Fixed -> {i -> σ e/(γ + ν)}]
```

[image]

Now we can see the stable equilibrium `eq[[2]]` in a 2D slice.

I haven't built in support for 3D isoclines & streams yet, because I usually find them hard to see.  But here's a start at it:

```
isoclines = ContourPlot3D[
  Evaluate[EcoEqns[] /. ZeroLHS /. var_[t] -> var],
  {s, 0, 1}, {e, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 1},
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.8], Mesh -> None, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{s, e, i}, s + e + i < 1], 
  AxesLabel -> {s, e, i}];

streams = StreamPlot3D[
  Evaluate[EcoEqns[] /. RHS /. var_[t] -> var],
  {s, 0, 1}, {e, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {s, e, i}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{s, e, i}, s + e + i < 1], 
  StreamStyle -> {Black, Thin}, StreamColorFunction -> None, 
  StreamPoints -> Fine];

Show[isoclines, streams]
```

[image]

**Addition**

Given your interests, I suggest including $R$ as a dynamic variable.  You can set colors for each variable with `Color` in [SetModel](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/docs/ref/SetModel.nb).

```
SetModel[{
  Pop[pop] -> {
    Component[s] -> {Equation :> ν (1 - c) - β s i - ν s + ξ r - ρ s, Color -> Blue},
    Component[e] -> {Equation :> β s i - σ e - ν e, Color -> Orange},
    Component[i] -> {Equation :> σ e - γ i - ν i, Color -> Red},
    Component[r] -> {Equation :> ν c + γ i - ν r - ξ r + ρ s, Color -> Green}
    }, Parameters :> {β > 0, γ > 0, ξ > 0, σ > 0, ν > 0, ρ > 0, c > 0}}]
```

To simulate:

```
β = 4; γ = 1/7; σ = 1/3; ξ = 1/14; c = 0.8; ν = (1.9/100)/365; ρ = 0.5;
sol = EcoSim[{s -> 0.25, e -> 0.25, i -> 0.25, r -> 0.25}, 100];
PlotDynamics[sol, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

To plot the dynamics of one variable vs another, use [RuleListPlot](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/docs/ref/RuleListPlot.nb).

```
RuleListPlot[sol, {e, i}]
```

[image]

Here's a grid of all pairwise combinations:

```
GraphicsGrid[
  Table[RuleListPlot[sol, {var1, var2}], {var1, {s, e, i, r}}, {var2, {s, e, i, r}}],
  Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer yet again! Is there a way to plot say $s$ vs $r$? I am reading a paper(their model is a little more complex) but very similar. I can attach it in the question as an edit if you'd like to see. They have managed to produce results that I am unable to produce(albeit quite close), maybe you can try?

Comment: Sure, attach the paper and I'll take a look when I have time.

Comment: It will give me coding errors again for some reason but I have attached it. The main interest is the solution to the ODE system and the phase plots.

Comment: BTW you need to use $$ to mark LaTeX code

Comment: Based on the paper, I assume you don't want isoclines or streams, just plotting a single trajectory.  Since `r` is only defined algebraically, the easiest thing to do is `ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{s[t], 1 - s[t] - e[t] - i[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 100},  AspectRatio -> 1]`.  For variables that are listed as `Components` you could use `RuleListPlot[sol, {s, e}]`, so another approach would be to explicitly model `r` as well.

Comment: I want the isoclines as all models I have considered, I have used your package. I tried something similar and I can get the solutions to the ODE system but I cant get the phase plots. I will attach the solution plot soon

Comment: Your system is 4D, reduced to 3D by the constraint $S+E+I+R=1$.  Therefore the isoclines will be surfaces in 3D space as I've shown above.  You could also take 2D slices as I've shown above, but it's not showing the full picture.  To plot the dynamics of one variable vs another, use `ParametericPlot`.  It's not clear what else needs to be answered here.

Comment: To put it simply, I want to recreate what the paper has done for my model(using your eco package, isoclines are shown). Maybe I should post a separate question?

Comment: I have a feeling that "help me recreate this paper" would be seen as outside the scope of this site.  The usual emphasis is on more narrow, technical questions related to Mathematica, particularly ones that might help others.

Comment: No problem, I have figured it! two last questions: 1) is there a way to change the colour for $e$ and $i$ in the phase plots? I wish $e$ to be orange and $i$ to be red to match my code. 2) why is the red highlight around the phase plot?

Comment: 1) Use `Color` in `SetModel`.  2) `EcoPhasePlane` plots 2D isoclines, which is not appropriate for your 3D model without fixing one variable.   Use `RuleListPlot` to plot dynamics in this 2D slice instead.  See my addition for details.  BTW, a tip: try to use the same symbols in your different codes as in the paper - makes debugging easier!

Comment: Having just skimmed through, this is fantastic! I will have a deeper look when I get some time. Thank you, this is greatly appreciated dear friend! I may have some additional questions aha

Comment: When you plotted your 2d slices earlier, I didn't see the red highlight albeit we used the same code, why?

Comment: The `Fixed` option in `PlotEcoPhasePlane` fixes one of the variables, taking a 2D slice through the 3D phase space.

Comment: Thats what i used, i got the error "BoxRatios::nlist3: 1 is not a list of three numbers."

Comment: When I tried performing Routh-Hurwitz criteria manually, the third condition fails, can you help? I will post a new question.